# Variance / Covariance Matrix - mean of squared errors

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, covariance-matrix

I'm trying to build a stats library. I'm following along with the tutorial on multiple regression analysis here: http://reliawiki.org/index.php/Multiple_Linear_Regression_Analysis

I have the following test case which works fine:

```
 describe "Multiple Linear Regression Analysis", () ->
    outcome = new S.ColumnVector([
        251.3, 251.3, 248.3, 267.5, 273.0, 276.5, 270.3, 274.9, 285.0,
        290.0, 297.0, 302.5, 304.5, 309.3, 321.7, 330.7, 349.0
    ])
    X = new S.Matrix([
        [1, 41.9, 29.1]
        [1, 43.4, 29.3]
        [1, 43.9, 29.5]
        [1, 44.5, 29.7]
        [1, 47.3, 29.9]
        [1, 47.5, 30.3]
        [1, 47.9, 30.5]
        [1, 50.2, 30.7]
        [1, 52.8, 30.8]
        [1, 53.2, 30.9]
        [1, 56.7, 31.5]
        [1, 57.0, 31.7]
        [1, 63.5, 31.9]
        [1, 65.3, 32.0]
        [1, 71.1, 32.1]
        [1, 77.0, 32.5]
        [1, 77.8, 32.9]
    ])
    [coefficients, errors] = outcome.regression_coefficients(X)
    B = [-153.51, 1.24, 12.08]

    it "regression analysis produces correct coefficients", () ->
        for i in [0..coefficients.mtx[0].length - 1]
            expect(coefficients.mtx[0][i]).to.be.closeTo(B[i], 0.1)
```

That is, I'm calculating the same regression coefficients as the ones on the wiki page.

My implementation for the var/cov matrix is simple (is it correct)?

```
var_covar_matrix: (X) ->
  [B, e] = @regression_coefficients(X)
  sigma2 = e.pow(2).colmeans().mtx[0][0]
  return X.transposed().mult(X).inverse().smult(sigma2)
```

So, `e` is the errors vector:

```
  [ [ 1.312707260212136 ],
     [ -2.961848308696972 ],
     [ -8.997680608112717 ],
     [ 7.042614765522103 ],
     [ 6.657718946271814 ],
     [ 5.077032963034753 ],
     [ -4.034927009431669 ],
     [ -4.700461193935439 ],
     [ 0.9706229730474547 ],
     [ 4.266898332915616 ],
     [ -0.3180451043184007 ],
     [ 2.393867250164476 ],
     [ -6.074304666210992 ],
     [ -4.712241883633453 ],
     [ -0.7050721790290027 ],
     [ -3.846480798377627 ],
     [ 8.629599256689403 ] ],
```

I take the mean of the squares and get `24.904358254480343` which seems right.

But, when I multiply that by `(X * X_t)^(-1)`, the inverse of `X'X`, I get a var/covar:

```
[ [ 8380.84853342069, 30.58962484646245, -325.97441022352643 ],
  [ 30.58962484646245, 0.1282247440204739, -1.2196518304076294 ],
  [ -325.9744102235264, -1.2196518304076291, 12.734165897988822 ] ]
```

Which looks a lot like the one that is given in the wiki. But, it seems to off by a factor. The matrix that is given looks like:

```
[
        [10176.7446, 37.1445, -395.8261]
        [37.1445, 0.1557, -1.481]
        [-395.8261, -1.481, 15.4629]
]
```

Any hints as to where I went wrong? Somehow it seems like my mean squared error is off. But, it looks ok. Maybe I'm missing a `+ 1` somewhere.

Update: If I divide by `14` instead of `17` to obtain the "mean" of the squared errors, I get the "correct" result. What is the reason for using `n-3` for the number to divide by when taking the mean of the squared errors? Can I generalize this to be `n-X.width`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to calculate (in the same notation as the page you linked): 
$$ C = \hat\sigma^2 (X^TX)^{-1}$$

Remember the formula for $\hat\sigma^2$:
$$ \hat\sigma^2 = \frac{(y - X\hat\beta)^T(y - X\hat\beta)}{n - p} $$

where $n$ is the number of rows in $X$, and $p$ is the number of columns.  $n - p$ is the *degrees of freedom*.